# Zeppelin: How to restart sparkContext in zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am using Isolated mode of zeppelins spark interpreter, with this mode it will start a new job for each notebook in spark cluster. I want to kill the job via zeppelin when the notebook execution is completed. For this I did `sc.stop` this stopped the sparkContext and the job is also stopped from spark cluster. But next time when I try to run the notebook its not starting the `sparkContext` again. So how to do that?

Answer (score 29):

It's a bit counter intuitive but you need to access the interpreter menu tab instead of stopping `SparkContext` directly:

- go to interpreter list.

  [image: interpreter list]
- find Spark interpreter and click <kbd>restart</kbd> in the right upper corner:

  [image: spark intepreter]

Comment: isn't there any other apart from manually restarting interpreter?

Comment: When using `Zeppelin` for `Spark` on `EMR` and loading *external `fat-jar`* from `S3`, I've found that **restarting the interpreter *just once* doesn't suffice**. Suppose I had loaded *fat-jar* from `S3`, which has since been upgraded. To ensure that *new jar* is loaded in the `interpreter`, I do this: (1) Edit interpreter `dependencies` and remove the existing jar, save changes (2) Restart the interpreter (3) Again edit the *interpreter dependencies* and add the new jar (it could have the same path as before) (4) Restart the interpreter once more

Answer (score 10):

You can restart the interpreter for the notebook in the interpreter bindings (gear in upper right hand corner) by clicking on the restart icon to the left of the interpreter in question (in this case it would be the spark interpreter).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAm7a.png]

Answer (score 7):

While working with Zeppelin and Spark I also stumbled upon the same problem and made some investigations. After some time, my first conclusion was that:

- Stopping the SparkContext can be accomplished by using `sc.stop()` in a paragraph
- Restarting the SparkContext only works by using the UI (Menu -> Interpreter -> Spark Interpreter -> click on `restart` button)

However, since the UI allows restarting the Spark Interpreter via a button press, why not just reverse engineer the API call of the `restart` button! The result was, that `restarting` the Spark Interpreter sends the following HTTP request:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/interpreter/setting/restart/spark
```

Fortunately, Zeppelin has the ability to work with multiple interpreters, where one of them is also a `shell` Interpreter. Therefore, i created two paragraphs:

**The first paragraph was for stopping the SparkContext whenever needed:**

```
%spark
// stop SparkContext
sc.stop()
```

**The second paragraph was for restarting the SparkContext programmatically:**

```
%sh
# restart SparkContext
curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/api/interpreter/setting/restart/spark
```

After stopping and restarting the SparkContext with the two paragraphs, I run another paragraph to check if restarting worked...and it worked! So while this is no official solution and more of a workaround, it is still legit as we do nothing else than "pressing" the `restart` button within a paragraph!

Zeppelin version: 0.8.1

Comment: This didn't work for me on EMR.  When running the curl command via the shell interpreter, I got the following error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused`

Answer (score 2):

I'm investigated the problem why sc stop in spark in yarn-client. I find that it's the problem of spark itself(Spark version >=1.6). In spark client mode, the AM connect to the Driver via RPC connection, there are two connections. It setup NettyRpcEndPointRef to connect to the driver's service 'YarnSchedulerBackEnd' of server 'SparkDriver', and other another connection is  EndPoint 'YarnAM'.

In these RPC connections between AM and Driver ,there are no heartbeats. So the only way AM know the Driver is connectted or not is that the OnDisconnected method in EndPoint 'YarnAM'. The disconnect message of driver and AM connetcion though NettyRpcEndPointRef will  'postToAll' though RPCHandler to the EndPoint 'YarnAM'. When the TCP connetion between them disconnected, or keep alive message find the tcp not alive(2 hours maybe in Linux system), it will mark the application SUCCESS.

So when the Driver Monitor Process find the yarn application state change to SUCCESS, it will stop the sc.

So the root cause is that , in Spark client, there are no retry connect to the driver to check the driver is live or not,but just mark the yarn application as quick as possible.Maybe Spark can modify this issue.