# Job 65 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I'm working on a shared Apache Zeppelin server. Almost every day, I try to run a command and get this error: `Job 65 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down`

I would love to learn more about what causes the SparkContext to shut down. My understanding is Zeppelin is a kube app that sends commands to a machine for the processing.

When a SparkContext shuts down, does that mean my bridge to the Spark cluster is down? And, if that's the case, how can I cause the bridge to the spark cluster to go down?

In this example, it happened when I was trying to upload data to S3.

This is the code

```
val myfiles = readParquet(
    startDate=ew LocalDate(2020, 4, 1),
    endDate=ew LocalDate(2020, 4, 7)
)

log_events.createOrReplaceTempView("log_events")

val mySQLDF = spark.sql(s"""
    select [6 columns]
    from myfiles 
    join [other table]
    on [join_condition]
"""
)

mySQLDF.write.option("maxRecordsPerFile", 1000000).parquet(path)
// mySQLDF has 3M rows and they're all strings or dates
```

This is the stacktrace error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:198)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:156)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:676)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:285)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:271)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:229)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:566)
  ... 48 elided
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 44 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:972)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:970)
  at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:970)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:2286)
  at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:84)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:2193)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$6.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1949)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1340)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1948)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend$MonitorThread.run(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:777)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:167)
  ... 70 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Job cancelled because SparkContext was shut down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984506/job-cancelled-because-sparkcontext-was-shut-down)

Comment: Nope, because I'm using spark with hadoop

Comment: Can you post full stack trace. & also what you are executing code if possible ? mostly because some memory issues

Comment: Great, I posted the stack trace and the code. I pulled one example, but this happens with many different blocks of code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your job is getting aborted at the write step. `Job aborted.` is the exception message for that, which is leading to the Spark Context being shutdown.

Look into optimising the write step, `maxRecordsPerFile` might be the culprit; maybe try a lower number.. you currently have 1M records in a file!

---

In general, `Job ${job.jobId} cancelled because SparkContext was shut down` just means that it's an exception due to which the DAG couldn't continue and needs to Error out. Its the [Spark scheduler throwing this error](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/95aec091e4d8a45e648ce84d32d912f585eeb151/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/DAGScheduler.scala#L1027) when it faces an exception, it might be an exception that is unhandled in your code or a job failure due to any other reason. And as the DAG scheduler is stopped, the entire application will get stopped(this message is part of Cleanup).

---

To your questions -

> When a SparkContext shuts down, does that mean my bridge to the Spark cluster is down?

SparkContext represents the connection to a Spark cluster, so if its dead it means you can't run run job on to it as you lost the link! On Zepplin, you can just restart the SparkContext (Menu -> Interpreter -> Spark Interpreter -> restart)

> And, if that's the case, how can I cause the bridge to the spark cluster to go down?

With SparkException/Error in Jobs or manually using `sc.stop()`

Comment: Thank you, how do I restart a SparkContext?

Comment: On Zepplin  Goto `Menu -> Interpreter -> Spark Interpreter -> Click restart` 
(or 
there is also a [hack mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56754005/2142994) )